# How to split the input based by comparing two dataframes in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split, keyword

I am trying to take the input and keyword in the two tables from the database. So am using pandas to read both the tables and using the respective columns for splitting up of data and then write back the output in the same table in DB.

**My input:**

**Original_Input**

```
LARIDENT SRL
MIZUHO Corporation Gosen Factory
ZIMMER MANUFACTURING BV
GALT MEDICAL CORP
MIZUHO AMERICA INC
AVENT S de RL de CV
LUV N CARE LTD
STERIS ISOMEDIX PUERTO RICO INC
MEDISTIM INC
Cadence Science Inc
TECHNOLOGIES SA
AMG Mdicale Co Inc
```

**My keyword table:**

```
**Name_Extension**                 **Company_Type**        **Priority**
  co llc                             Company LLC                2
  Pvt ltd                            Private Limited            8
  Corp                               Corporation                4
  CO Ltd                             Company Limited            3
  inc                                Incorporated               5
  CO                                 Company                    1
  ltd                                Limited                    7
  llc                                LLC                        6
  Corporation                        Corporation                4
  & Co                               Company                    1
  Company Limited                    Company Limited            3
  Limited                            Limited                    7
  Co inc                             Company Incorporated       9
  AB                                  AB                        10
  SA                                  SA                        11
  S A                                 SA                        11
  GmbH                                GmbH                      12
  Sdn Bhd                             Sdn Bhd                   13
  llp                                 LLP                       14
  co llp                              LLP                       14
  SA DE CV                           SA DE CV                   19
  Company                            Company                    1 
  Coinc                              Company Incorporated       9
  Coltd                              Company Limited            3
```

So if the input(in table 1) has any of the name extension(this is in table 2) then it has to be split and put in as Core_input and Type_input columns where core input will contain the company names and type_input will contain the company type(from table 2 column 2) and it has to be checked with the priority.

**My output will be:**

```
Core_Input                                         Type_input
    NULL                                               NULL
    NULL                                               NULL
    NULL                                               NULL
   GALT MEDICAL                                    Corporation
   MIZUHO AMERICA                                   Incorporated
     NULL                                               NULL
   LUV N CARE                                         Limited
 STERIS ISOMEDIX PUERTO RICO                         Incorporated
    MEDISTIM                                         Incorporated
   Cadence Science                                   Incorporated
```

**My Code:**

```
k1=[]
k2=[]

df1=pd.read_sql('select * from [dbo].[company_Extension]',engine)

for inp1 in df1['Name_Extension']:
    k1.append(inp1.strip())

for inp2 in df1['Company_Type']:
    k2.append(inp2.strip())


p=1
p1=max(df1['Priority'])

for k1 in df1['Name_Extension']:
    for k2 in df1['Company_Type']:
      #for pr in df1['Priority']:
         for i in df['Cleansed_Input']:
            while p<=p1:
                if re.search(r'[^>]*?\s'+str(k1).strip(),str(i).strip(),re.I) and (p == (pr for pr in 
                                                                               df1['Priority'])):
                    splits = i.str.split(str(k1),re.I)

                    df['Core_Input'] = splits[0] #df['Cleansed_Input'].str.replace(str(k1),'',re.I) 

                    df['Type_input'] = str(k2)
                 p=p+1
data.to_sql('Testtable', con=engine, if_exists='replace',index= False)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Edit:

```
df=pd.read_sql('select * from [dbo].[TempCompanyName]',engine)

df1=pd.read_sql('select * from [dbo].[company_Extension]',engine)

ext_list = df1['Name_Extension']
type_list =df1['Company_Type']

for i, j in df.iterrows():
    comp_name = df['Original_Input'][i]
    for idx, ex in enumerate(ext_list):
        if re.search(rf'\b{ex}\b', comp_name,re.IGNORECASE):
            df['Core_Input'] = type_list[idx]
            df['Type_input'].iloc[i] = comp_type

print(df)
df.to_sql('TempCompanyName', con=engine, if_exists='replace',index= False)


Edit:
ext_list = df1['Name_Extension']
type_list =df1['Company_Type']

for i, j in enumerate(df['Cleansed_Input']):
    comp_name = df['Cleansed_Input'][i]

    for idx, ex in enumerate(ext_list):
        comp_name.replace('.,','')
        if re.search(rf'(\b{ex}\b)', comp_name, re.I):
            comp_type = type_list[idx]
            df['Type_input'].iloc[i]= comp_type
            # Delete the extension name from company name
            updated_comp_name = 
            re.sub(rf'(\b{str(ex).upper()}\b)','',str(comp_name).upper())
            # Above regex is leaving space post word removal adding space 
            from next word becomes 2 spaces
            updated_comp_name = str(updated_comp_name).replace('  ',' ')
            # Update the company name
            df['Core_Input'].iloc[i] = updated_comp_name
```

Comment: question is not clear,, 2 tables - table a and table b - x is the input collected from table a and y is the input collected from table b,,, then what to spit and what is the base to split like it is space, some string , or some special keyword..

Comment: Its the keyword that is present in table 2. table 2 has three columns. if the words in 1st column of table 2 is present at the end of the input in table 1 then that should be split. Eg. Cadence Science Inc .This is the input in table1 and it has the keyword inc which is in 1st column of table 2. so it should be split and given as Cadence Science , Incorporation. Inc should be abbreviated and put in another column. the abbre are also present in table2, 2nd column

Comment: I gave the input and output tables clearly but don know why it is not aligned properly here

Comment: check below and mark if it is the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Hope below lines help you to get the solution...i am not using SQL due to some reason, but taken your data in 2 different excels...you need to add a column Type in input table before run the code...

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy
import re

input_df = pd.read_excel('input.xlsx',sheet_name='Sheet1')
exts_df = pd.read_excel('exts.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1')

# Check if correct data is loaded
print(input_df.head())

ext_list = exts_df['Name_Extension']
type_list =exts_df['Company_Type']

for i, j in input_df.iterrows():
    comp_name = input_df['Company Names'][i]
    for idx, ex in enumerate(ext_list):
        if re.search(rf'\b{ex}\b', comp_name,re.IGNORECASE):
            comp_type = type_list[idx]
            input_df['Type'].iloc[i] = comp_type
            # Delete teh extension name from company name
            updated_comp_name = re.sub(rf'\b{str(ex).upper()}\b','',str(comp_name).upper())
            # Above regex is leaving space post word removal adding space from next word becomes 2 spaces
            updated_comp_name = str(updated_comp_name).replace('  ',' ')
            # Update the company name
            input_df['Company Names'].iloc[i] = updated_comp_name

print(input_df)
input_df.to_excel('output.xlsx', index=False)
```

output post removal extension from input Company Name Column mapping Company_Type ...

[image] ...

Comment: So do I have to add anything in the Type column and may I know for what it is. Cos I tried adding my sql tables to your code replacing the places of excel but output is diff.

Comment: I have added an EDIT. Please check

Comment: pandas work on data frame irrespective to source,,, and name of columns is should be mind working with pandas,,once you upload your frame from db check if proper data is loaded,. print(df.[ 'column_name ' ].head)..... else ,, put your both the table mentioned in the question in 2 different excels,, input.xlsx which have a column name Company Name and another Type (you need to add)....and another excel exts.xlsx which have 3 columns of your keyword table ,, just remove star sign from names....

Comment: i have updated the code to update company name without Name_Extension

Comment: Let me try this, but our rule is to use the input from the database table and then process in python and then write back to database table. We are not allowed to use excel

Comment: Hi Hietsh this is working fine. Am able to take the input from table and write back to it. But there is one input where am not getting the ouput correctly. Can you help me with that. I tried some steps but didn't work. EG.                                                
 Input: TRULY INSTRUMENT CO., LTD.                                                          Output should be: TRULY INSTRUMENT    company limited.                                                             But am getting TRULY INSTRUMENT CO.   Limited                         which is wrong

Comment: CO., LTD.  -  this input was not given in the list of the question , replace dot and comma in side the second for loop. If it a answer for given question , mark it as answer. inside second for loop -  ex.replace('.,',' ')

Comment: Yeah I forgot. But where do I have to put the replace function? I mean inside second for loop should I put separately or along with any other statement

Comment: in second for loop keep this as the first line.......ex.replace('.,',' ')

Comment: Its stil the same. I have given an edit in the question. Is that correct?

Comment: Its working if i have only . and , But if the input is like TRULY INSTRUMENT CO., LTD. its not working though I replaced ,. and blank space. So what I did was I add CO LTD to the regex pattern and it worked. But don know whether it is efficient.