# Adding value to new column based on if two other columns match

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe (df1) that looks like this;

| title | score | id | timestamp | Stock_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Biocryst ($BCRX) continues to remain undervalued | 120 | mfuz84 | 2021-01-28 21:32:10 |  |

...and then continues with 44000 something more rows. I have another dataframe (df2) that looks like this;

| Company name | Symbol |
| --- | --- |
| BioCryst Pharmaceuticals, Inc. | BCRX |
| GameStop | GME |
| Apple Inc. | AAPL |

...containing all nasdaq and NYSE listed stocks. What I want to do now however, is to add the symbol of the stock to the column "Stock_name" in df1. In order to do this, I want to match the df1[title] with the df2[Symbol] and then based on what symbol has a match in the title, add the corresponding stock name (df2[Company name]) to the df1[Stock_name] column. If there is more than one stock name in the title, I want to use the first one mentioned.

Is there any easy way to do this?

Comment: not exact answer but might help you..https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60448654/how-to-split-the-input-based-by-comparing-two-dataframes-in-pandas/60462928#60462928

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried with this little dataset and it's working, let me know if you have some problems

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"title" :   ["Biocryst ($BCRX) continues to remain undervalued", "AAPL is good, buy it"], 'score' : [120,420]   , 'Stock_name' : ["",""]    })
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Company name' : ['BioCryst Pharmaceuticals, Inc.','GameStop','Apple Inc.'], 'Symbol' : ["BCRX","GME","AAPL"]})

df1
                                               title    score   Stock_name
0   Biocryst ($BCRX) continues to remain undervalued    120 
1   AAPL is good, buy it                                420


df2
                     Company name   Symbol
0   BioCryst Pharmaceuticals, Inc.  BCRX
1   GameStop                        GME
2   Apple Inc.                      AAPL

for j in range(0,len(df2)):
  for i in range(0,len(df1)):
    if df2['Symbol'][j] in df1['title'][i]:
      df1['Stock_name'][i] = df2['Symbol'][j]


df1

                                               title    score   Stock_name
0   Biocryst ($BCRX) continues to remain undervalued    120     BCRX
1   AAPL is good, buy it                                420     AAPL
```

Comment: I'm getting the following error; "TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not Series". I've tried running the following "df2["Symbol"]= df2["Symbol"].astype(str)" but unfortunately, this did not seem to fix my problem of getting the error. The code does work when I manually create a new dataframe with a few entries in it. Any ideas as to why this happens? Any help is very much appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

First, I think you should create a dictionary based on `df2`.

```
symbol_lookup = dict(zip(df2['Symbol'],df2['Company name']))
```

Then you need a function that will parse the `title` column. If you can rely on stock symbols being preceded by a dollar sign, you can use the following:

```
def find_name(input_string):
    for symbol in input_string.split('$'):
        #if the first four characters form 
        #a stock symbol, return the name
        if symbol_lookup.get(symbol[:4]):
            return symbol_lookup.get(symbol[:4])
        #otherwise check the first three characters
        if symbol_lookup.get(symbol[:3]):
            return symbol_lookup.get(symbol[:3])
```

You could also write a function based on expecting the symbols to be in parentheses. If you can't rely on either, it would be more complicated.

Finally, you can apply your function to the `title` column:

```
df1['Stock_name'] = df1['title'].apply(find_name)
```